# How to use slugs in routes

Tags: laravel, routes, slug

Is there a way to use slugs in my routes like instead `domain/technicalInformation` it would be `domain/technical-information`. Thank You!

PagesController.php

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{    
    public function technicalInformation(){
        return view('pages.technical-information');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/technicalInformation','ConsumerController@technicalInformation')->name('technical-information');
```

Comment: you may need to show us some more code, is `technical-information` from your db?

Comment: No, `technicalInformation` is a function used in my controller. I read some docs about slugs, does it uses a db? I am not using slugs right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you just change to this and it should work.

```php
Route::get('/technical-information','ConsumerController@technicalInformation')->name('technical-information');
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!  I thought editing that part would not call my  routes correctly.